# Problems with ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

So I'm trying to include a partial within another partial with a simple ng-view but it throws me this error: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!. I have done some research about it and according to what I've read this is caused by trying to change some model data when the page loads. Still, I'm not using any models, the only thing I'm trying to use here is the ng-include itself. Here's the code:

```
<section id = "content">
 <div ng-include = "template.url"></div>
</section>
```

In my controller file:

```
$scope.templates = [
  {'name' : 'partial2.html', 'url' : 'partial2.html'},
  {'name' : 'partial3.html', 'url' : 'partial3.html'}
];

$scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
```

My partial2.html code:

```
<form name = "frmSelect" id = "frmSelect" method = "post" class = "content-space">
 <select id="providers" name = "providers" class = "form-control" ng-model = "provider">
  <option>Account1</option>
  <option>Account2</option>
  <option>Account3</option>
  <option>Account4</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Note: I already tried by removing the ng-model but the output stills the same.

Any thoughts on this error?

Comment: You dont need the single quotes when evaluating a expression.

Comment: Everything looks fine. The error must be in another part of your code. Can you post your whole controller file?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function for that:

In the view:

```
<section id = "content">
  <div ng-include  src = "templateUrl()"></div>
</section>
```

And the controller would be like this:

```
$scope.templateUrl = function() {
   return  $scope.templates[0].url;
}
```

[This is a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9znT3GPfUYU4ZynUcVqw?p=preview)

Comment: FWIW, he is using the exact same code from the documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude Not that using a function is a bad idea, it just doesn't address the problem at hand.

Comment: He was not using the exact same code from the documentation. The documentation code uses: <ng-include="template.url">, while he uses <ng-include src="template.url"></div>. The difference is that he was using "src" attribute in the first question (before editing). So if his intentions are to use "src" (for any reason, even it's not in documentation), the purpose is to show that it would work in a different other than the documented one.